# C# Regex And Curly Braces For Repetition

Tags: c#, regex, repeat

I'm relatively new to regex and still struggling along. Repetition is currently the source of my frustration. I've been asked to write a regex matching mobile phone numbers of the format +447 and then a string a 9 digits. After some reading, I have come up with:

```
string num = @"+447123456789";
string reg = "^[+447]([0-9]{9})$";
Regex filter = new Regex(reg);
```

Assuming it'd read, must start with +447 ([...] specifying explicit characters to match) followed by any 9 digits 0-9, however `filter.IsMatch(num)` always returns false. I tried replacing the {9} with + and it returned true, though it also returned true when it should have failed (i.e. num holding the value "+4").

Given my results, I think I've misunderstood the use of [...] (otherwise a simple +4 shouldn't return true) and {...} (I understood it to mean the previous sequence (in my case, [0-9]) repeated ... times, in my case, 9).

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
CprlKleg

Comment: [+447] means one of +, 4 or 7. Not all of "+447"

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've learned something today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `^\+447(\d{9})$`.

You must know that `+` is a special charater in Regex and hence need a backward slash character to avoid it. `+ or . or $` and many others are treated as special character.

`\d` denotes only digits.
`\w` denotes characters + digits + underscore

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ohh, I'm starting to see. Many thanks :). So by keeping the literal 447 outside of square braces tells it that it must be matched exactly?

Comment: Accepted for the more detailed response. Thank you

Comment: Yes. Anything written as is will be matched for exact text.

Answer (score 3):

Try `string reg = "^\+447([0-9]{9})$";` or `string reg = "^\+447(\d{9})$";`

Comment: Many thanks! both work wonderfully. So what does using the \ character before +447 mean? How does it know when to stop matching following the \?

Comment: Don't worry - I will accept. Just need to wait, apparently. Thanks again

Comment: The \+ is because + is a special character in regex meaning 'one or more' putting a backslash before it escapes it. The ^ and $ are anchors which match the beginning and end of the string or line you are matching against.